# Finding the percentage increase in the price of a share

Tags: percentages

At the close of one business day, a company's stock was trading at $\$24$ a share.
At the close of the next business day, the stock was trading at $\$27$ a share.
Find the percent of increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{27-24}{24}=\frac{3}{24}=\frac{1}{8}=12.5$%

Comment: How did you get 3/24?

Comment: We are looking for the change from Day 1 to Day 2

Comment: We take the change from Day 1 to Day 2 and compare that to the whole Day 1

Comment: The change from Day 1 to Day 2 is 3. Comparing that to the whole Day 1 is 3/24, because Day 1 was 24 a stock. 3/24 = 1/8, which is equivalent to 12.5%